# PHP warning complains that MYSQL_STORE_RESULT will not be supported in newer versions and the code also doesn't execute properly/at all

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm struggling to ascertain the proper way to use sql injection to perform an add query the code in question is as follows:

```
$affectedRows = 0;
foreach($twoDArray as $oneDArray){
    $columns = implode(", ",array_keys($oneDArray));
    $escaped_values = array_map('serialize', array_keys($oneDArray));
    $values = implode(',',$escaped_values);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `entry_tab`($columns) VALUES ($values)";
    mysqli_query($database, $sql,[$resultmode = MYSQL_STORE_RESULT]);
    echo "\n done one \n";
    $affectedRows += 1;
}
```

The error I'm getting is as follows:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant MYSQL_STORE_RESULT - assumed 'MYSQL_STORE_RESULT' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\main.php on line 60, in other words (mysqli_query($database, $sql,[$resultmode = MYSQL_STORE_RESULT]);)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT` 
actually this is default option so you can remove this just use

```
mysqli_query($database, $sql);
```

OR

```
mysqli_query($database, $sql, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to fix this error?:
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\main.php on line 60
Line in question:
mysqli_query($database, $sql,[$resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT]);

Comment: What $database has?

Comment: $database has to be a connection object not database name

Comment: $database = new PDO("mysql:host=$databaseHost;dbname=$databaseName", $dbUsername, $dbPassword,
            array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            )

        );

Comment: You should use PDO statements not mysqli  see here http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php

Answer (score 0):

Its probably best to use a pdo database connection.
Similar to this

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `entry_tab ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
  $conn->exec($sql);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```